# ComponentRenderer on CheckboxGroup make the label 'not clickable'

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin23

I have this CheckBoxGroup with a custom renderer:
[image]

It is working well EXCEPT you can't click on the label to select le checkbox.

Here is the renderer code:

```
 CheckboxGroup<EtatDossier> etatsCheckBox = new CheckboxGroup<>("Etats"
            , EtatDossier.DEPOSE
            , EtatDossier.ATTENTE_VERIFICATION_SAF
            , EtatDossier.ENTAME
            , EtatDossier.INSCRIPTION_FINALISEE
            , EtatDossier.INSCRIPTION_ABANDONNEE
        );
  etatsCheckBox.setRenderer(new ComponentRenderer<>(Label::new, (label, etat) -> {
        label.setText(switch (etat) {
            case DEPOSE, NON_CONFORME_SAF -> "DEVE";
            case ATTENTE_VERIFICATION_SAF, ATTENTE_ENCAISSEMENT, ATTENTE_SAISIE_EXO -> "DFC";
            case ENTAME, ATTENTE_MODIFS_PAR_ETUDIANT -> "Etudiant";
            case INSCRIPTION_FINALISEE -> "Finalisé";
            case INSCRIPTION_ABANDONNEE, INSCRIPTION_NON_FINALISEE -> "Erreur";
        });
        label.setTitle(etat.getTooltip());
        label.getStyle().set("color", etat.getCouleur());
    }));
```

How can I change this to make the label 'clickable' ?

Comment: Try to use Span::new instead of Label::new.